# 0 size font awesome icons after converting header to standalone component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After a friend helped me make my header a standalone component, my icons for my navigation buttons have disappeared. I'm trying to troubleshoot on my own, but I haven't been able to determine why it's happening.

Here's what I believe is the relevant code:

```js
    <MyLink href="/articles" className={which == "articles" ? "on" : ""}><i aria-hidden className={"far fa-newspaper"}></i>ARTICLES</MyLink>
    <MyLink href="/benchmarks" className={which == "benchmarks" ? "on" : ""}><i aria-hidden className={"fas fa-chart-line"}></i>BENCHMARKS</MyLink>
    <MyLink href="/downloads" className={which == "downloads" ? "on" : ""}><i aria-hidden className={"fas fa-download"}></i>DOWNLOADS</MyLink>
    <MyLink href="/contribute" className={which == "contribute" ? "on" : ""}><i aria-hidden className={"fas fa-code-branch"}></i>CONTRIBUTE</MyLink>
    <MyLink href="/FAQ"><i aria-hidden className={"far fa-comments"}></i>FAQ</MyLink> {/*className={which5 == "FAQ" ? "on" : ""}*/}
    <MyLink href="/purchase"><i aria-hidden className={"fas fa-store"}></i>PURCHASE</MyLink>
```

And here's a picture of the issue:[image: 0_size_icons]

And here's what I've tried so far:

- `style={{width:"24", height: "24"}}`
- getting rid of `aria-hidden`
- adding curly braces around className - THIS FIXED IT FOR HALF A SECOND, I SWEAR!!

Apologies if the tags are wrong. Not sure how exactly to tag this issue.

Comment: Your screenshot has the wrong element selected. Anchors don't always swell to the size of their contents. What styles are being applied to `.fa`? Is the FA library loading?

Comment: My CSS is not applying any styles ```.fa```, and I'm not sure how to check if the FA library is loading. I'm not getting any errors in the terminal I'm running my local instance in, so I would assume that it's loading?